# Is this an example of a Nachfeld?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Wenn es so war … und wenn herauskäme, **dass sie verwandt waren ***mit einem Paar von***** – nein, das würde er einfach nicht ertragen.

Im talking about the part in italics and bold.
It very much seems so, but I need confirmation because I'm a learner. I can't see what else would be the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. Normally, the verb is at the end in a subordinate clause, but in the *dass* clause, there is a "mit..."-prepositional that follows after the verb, and that position is called the *Nachfeld*.

> Sie sah, dass er sich bewegte **wie ein Betrunkener**.
> Markus muss eine Strafe zahlen, weil er zu schnell gefahren ist **in der Stadt.**

On a different level, the *dass* clause as a whole is also in the Nachfeld of the *wenn* clause that it is grammatically part of.

> Wenn herauskäme, **dass sie verwandt sind mit den Maiers**, würde er es nicht ertragen.